# How big should a button image be?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, button

I'm trying to use a [`Button` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with both text and an image. The image is being drawn dynamically with a background to match the button background. The problem is I cannot find the proper size that the image will be drawn into; the button control seems to leave some unspecified border around the edges. The `Bounds`, `Size`, and `ClientSize` properties all have a height of 23 so there's no way to detect how much border is being drawn.

P.S. To clarify, the image is being drawn into its own `Graphic` and then the resulting bitmap is placed in the `Image` property.

Comment: Is it the 3D spacing that you are seeing?  If you set the style to flat, the padding should go away.  As for a way to know what that is, I'm still looking.

Comment: @JohnKoerner, I don't want this button to have a different style than all my other buttons.

Comment: I understand, I was just asking if that was indeed the cause of the extra border you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's hard coded as 4 pixels.  From ButtonBaseAdapter:

```
internal abstract class ButtonBaseAdapter
{
  protected static int buttonBorderSize = 4;
```

So that would be 8 pixels total to accommodate the left and right, or top and bottom.